# OpenGL sprite looses focus on fast move

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making simple app where user can move squares with finger on screen. First I'm checking if touch coords are on square to allow the move. Then square is moving along `GLSurfaceView#onTouchEvent` event coordinates.

It works OK. But when finger is moving too quick (like swipe) square looses the focus and stays still. It seems that OpenGL renders square *after* the move event occurs, so coordinates check fail.

Please point some keywords to figure out the question (googling gives same links again and again) or some docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need hold focus on sprite. If sprite got event "down" it holds focus until doesn't get "up" or "cancel" event. So, while sprite holds focus all touch events send to it.